# Как вставить карту с геокодированием?

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api, яндекс-карты

Как вставить карту как на странице в Яндексе https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/geocoder/?from=mapsapi , нужно самому писать обработчики событий или гдето есть готовый код?

Comment: Готовый код есть на предоставленной вами странице.

Comment: Блин, туплю, спасибо